# Display a new column in the table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-tsx

Goal:
Add a new column that contain a url link.
The content of the new column should be first name and lastname. The link should be
[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in all cell.

Problem:
I'm not used to react-table and how do I do´it?

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-ganguly-7w2d84

Info:
*newbie in react-table

Thank you!

---

app.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import styled from 'styled-components'
    import { useTable } from 'react-table'
    
    import makeData from './makeData'
    
    const Styles = styled.div`
      padding: 1rem;
    
      table {
        border-spacing: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
    
        tr {
          :last-child {
            td {
              border-bottom: 0;
            }
          }
        }
    
        th,
        td {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0.5rem;
          border-bottom: 1px solid black;
          border-right: 1px solid black;
    
          :last-child {
            border-right: 0;
          }
        }
      }
    `
    
    function Table({ columns, data }) {
      // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
      const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
      } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
      })
    
      // Render the UI for your table
      return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </thead>
          <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
              prepareRow(row)
              return (
                <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                  {row.cells.map(cell => {
                    return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                  })}
                </tr>
              )
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )
    }
    
    function App() {
      const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
          {
            Header: 'Name',
            columns: [
              {
                Header: 'First Name',
                accessor: 'firstName',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Last Name',
                accessor: 'lastName',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            Header: 'Info',
            columns: [
              {
                Header: 'Age',
                accessor: 'age',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Visits',
                accessor: 'visits',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Status',
                accessor: 'status',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Profile Progress',
                accessor: 'progress',
              },
              {
                Header: 'Profile Progress1',
                accessor: 'progress2',
              },          
            ],
          },
        ],
        []
      )
    
      const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(20), [])
    
      return (
        <Styles>
          <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
        </Styles>
      )
    }
    
    export default App


---------------

    makeData.js


import namor from 'namor'

const range = len => {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}

const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChance = Math.random()
  return {
    firstName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    lastName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30),
    visits: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    status:
      statusChance > 0.66
        ? 'relationship'
        : statusChance > 0.33
        ? 'complicated'
        : 'single',
  }
}

export default function makeData(...lens) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth]
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...newPerson(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeDataLevel()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we need to edit what we want to return from makeData function, to do that we should edit newPerson and add url, firstNameUrl and lastNameUrl. This sets us three new **accessors**

```
const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChance = Math.random();
  return {
    firstName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    lastName: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30),
    visits: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    url: " www.google.com",
    firstNameUrl: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    lastNameUrl: namor.generate({ words: 1, numbers: 0 }),
    status:
      statusChance > 0.66
        ? "relationship"
        : statusChance > 0.33
        ? "complicated"
        : "single"
  };
};
```

Now that we have new data keys we can simply tell react-table what to render out by editing column useMemo

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName"
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age"
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits"
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status"
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Url",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstNameUrl"
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastNameUrl"
          },
          {
            Header: "Url",
            accessor: "url"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );
```

I have edited the codepen, you can find it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-villani-dkw1ij)

@Edit

If you want to render a custom component then you can do this like below:

```
      {
        Header: "Last Name",
        accessor: "lastNameUrl",
        Cell: (e) => <a href="https://google.com"> {e.value} </a>
      }
```

This will render as link element with **accessor** value - I've also updated the codepen

Comment: Thank you for your help! I maybe have not explained clearly from my side.

There is one thing that is missing. When I press the www.google.com it should go to the page The url i column is a link

Comment: In other words, url column is a link that is clickable

Comment: The display should be first and lastname but not www.google.com. When you press the full name as a link,, you go to the google.com

Comment: @What'sUP ah right, hope I understood it right, i've updated my answer!